# Mongodb parameter on server

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, parameters

Hey guys i am using [mongodb](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/config.html) for my app and it works fine in localhost but when i want to push on server i have the parameter (in parameter.yml) : `mongodb_server`
that don't work.

In local i have this : `mongodb_server: “mongodb://localhost:27017”`

But i really don't know what i should put when i am on server.

I already tried : `mongodb_server: “mongodb://<ip_of_server>:27017”`

How can i know the port of the mongodb server ? and should i do like this : `“mongodb://<ip_of_server>:<port>”`

Ps : for example when i do this :

> php bin/console doctrine:mongodb:schema:update

I have this error :

> Failed to parse MongoDB URI: '“mongodb://:27017”'. Invalid URI Schema, expecting 'mongodb://' or 'mongodb+srv://'.

Comment: `localhost` always points to the host the code runs on. So on the server, also use `localhost`?

Comment: Same like on localhost: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017

Comment: yes i am using localhost on myserver, for example i have mysql on 127.0.0.1

Comment: @iiirxs i tryed this ... not working : Failed to parse MongoDB URI: '“mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017”'. Invalid URI Schema, expecting 'mongodb://' or 'mongodb+srv://'.

Comment: Might be silly, but try to remove the quotations from `“mongodb://<ip_of_server>:27017”`.

Comment: Looks like so: https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/config.html

Comment: Works without quotes !!! Woaw i don't understand it works with quotes in local, thx guys !

Comment: If you want you can make a response and i will validate it.

Comment: I'm not sure that would be long enough to make for an answer, but, I'll write it and you accept it, @LuisRosario, and we let admins decide if they want to delete it and settle for the comments above or leave it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/config.html), the value of `mongodb_server` in `parameters.yml` should be unquoted. See the example:

```
mongodb_server: mongodb://localhost:27017
```